# Angular material. error while importing MatIconRegistry

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-icon

I'ma using 'Angular: 10.0.14' with '@angular/material 10.2.7' and while trying to import  MatIconRegistry I get this error.

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/icon/icon-registry.d.ts:51:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of MaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

```
This likely means that the library (@angular/material/icon) which declares MatIconRegistry has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

51 export declare class MatIconRegistry implements OnDestroy {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/material/icon/icon-registry.d.ts:51:22 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of MaterialModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule, Component, Directive, or Pipe class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/material/icon) which declares MatIconRegistry has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

51 export declare class MatIconRegistry implements OnDestroy {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/material/material.module.ts:54:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of FoodTypeModule, but itself has errors

54 export class MaterialModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/material/material.module.ts:54:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of FoodItemModule, but itself has errors

540m export class MaterialModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/material/material.module.ts:54:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of IngredientTypeModule, but itself has errors

54 export class MaterialModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/material/material.module.ts:54:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of IngredientModule, but itself has errors

54 export class MaterialModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/food-item/food-item.module.ts:24:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

24 export class FoodItemModule {}
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/food-type/food-type.module.ts:25:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

25 export class FoodTypeModule {}
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/ingredient/ingredient.module.ts:25:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

25 export class IngredientModule {}
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/ingredient-type/ingredient-type.module.ts:25:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

25 export class IngredientTypeModule {}
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/material/material.module.ts:54:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but itself has errors

54 export class MaterialModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/material/material.module.ts:54:14 - error NG6003: Appears in the NgModule.exports of AppModule, but itself has errors

54 export class MaterialModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem has resolved by removing the importing of MatIconRegistry from my material module and just importing it in the component I want to use it in.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you tell us how you could import MatIconRegistry to the component ? I was not able to solve my issue using your answer.